# Как можно создать функцию, которая делила бы неделю на два типа? Python, datetime

Tags: python, telegram, datetime, schedule

Я совсем недавно начал писать на `Python` и решил написать своего бота, который работал бы, как расписание.

Вот сам код:

```py
url = "<токен>"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=url)


def get_chat_id(update):
    chat_id = update['message']["chat"]["id"]
    return chat_id


def get_message_text(update):
    message_text = update["message"]["text"]
    return message_text

def last_update(req):
    response = requests.get(req + "getUpdates")
    result = response["result"]
    return result[total_updates]


def send_message(chat_id, message_text):
    params = {"chat_id": chat_id, "text": message_text}
    response = requests.post(url + "sendMessage", data=params)
    return response


    def main():
    a = (datetime.date.today())
    update_id = last_update(url)["update_id"]
    while True:
        update = last_update(url)
        if update_id == update["update_id"]:
            if get_message_text(update).lower() == "пн" or get_message_text(update).lower() == "понедельник":
                send_message(get_chat_id(update), "пары на понедельник)
```

И в подобном духе на всю неделю, однако, я бы хотел спросить, как можно было бы создать скрипт, деливший недели на условный "числитель" и "знаменатель"? Нужно это, потому что в разные недели бывают разные пары. Буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Есть ли периодичность у этих типов недель ? А ещё у вас функция main уехала, я так понимаю.

Comment: `divmod(a, b)` возвращает кортеж из двух элементов, где 0-ый элемент это целая часть от деления `a` на `b`, а 1-ый это остаток от деления `a` на `b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
def what_week_now(message):
    nums = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().isocalendar()[1])
    dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y') 
    if (nums % 2) == 0:
        msg = f"Сьогодні {dt} (поточний тиждень №{nums})  -   <b>Знаменник</b>\n"
    if (nums % 2) != 0:
        msg = f"Сьогодні {dt} (поточний тиждень №{nums})  -   <b>Чисельник</b>\n"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, parse_mode='HTML')
```

UPDATE

```
def what_week_now(message):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    id_wd = dt.weekday()
    id_wt = int(dt.isocalendar()[1])%2
    dts = dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    msg = f"Сьогодні {dts} <b>({['Понеділок', 'Вівторок', 'Середа', 'Четвер', 'П`ятниця', 'Субота', 'Неділя'][id_wd]}, {['Чисельник','Знаменник'][id_wt]})</b>:\n"
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, msg, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

Если недели чередуются так: 1й тип, 2й тип, 1й тип, 2й тип, т.д.. Вам может подойти этот код:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def what_week_now():
    my_date = datetime(2020, 2, 3) # год, месяц, день опорной недели

    days = (datetime.now()-my_date).days # сколько дней разницы
    days -= days%7 # выравниваем на понедельник

    if days%14==0:
        return 1 # тот же тип недели
    else:
        return 0 # другой тип недели
```